# Building C program separately

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have two C files (first file need another one).

I should use `#include "XXX.C"`, but how I can make separately .obj files and then connect it (something like Borland's Project)? I read something about `link a, b` command but it doesn't work and I can't find any reference.

Thank you!

Comment: did you really try to open any search engine? It's very basic and popular problem. Try searching for `ld` or `makefile`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use #include "XXX.C". If you want to compile it separately.
You have to write a "XXX.h" with all functions you want to call.

After that, you can compile the files separately:

```
gcc -c YYY.c -o yyy.o
gcc -c XXX.c -o xxx.o
```

If you want to compile and link in a single pass:

```
gcc xxx.c yyy.c -o xxx
```

or if you want to  compile xxx.c and use the object file previous generated:

```
gcc xxc.c yyy.o -o xxx
```

or even:

```
gcc xxx.o yyy.o -o xxx
```

In the last example, gcc would call the linker, as there is no source code to compile.

But if you have more than two or three files, the next thing to check is how to use a Makefile.

Example:

xxx.c:

```
#include "yyy.h"

int x(int a)
{
   return a + 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   x(1);
   y(2);
   return 0;
}
```

yyy.c:

```
int y(int b)
{ 
   return b + 2;
}
```

yyy.h:

```
#pragma once
int y(int b);
```

Can be compiled separatelly:

```
gcc -c yyy.c -o yyy.o
gcc xxx.c yyy.o -o xxx
```

In this example, xxx.c calls a function defined on yyy.c.

Answer (score 1):

No, you should not use `#include "XXX.c"`. Only headers should be included; code files should be compiled separately from one another.

How exactly it is done depends on your compiler, but usually you simply list the files to the compiler one by one, like this:

```
gcc main.c helpers.c functions.c
```

Comment: Yes with headers I don't have any problem. It works also with C file but I want to build it separately. I have Code::Block. I try look for makefile or ld...

Answer (score 1):

You should have a .h ([header, with declarations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Header_file)) and (at least, one) .c (with implementations) files for each object file you want.

For more information on header files, go [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Header-Files.html).

Then you just need to do:

```
#include "XXX.h"
```

include the header file, not the .c file!